# IOT Central Azure Connector - Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, power-automate, azure-iot-central

My IOT Central application is not showing in the drop-down field within the IOT Central connector (within Logic Apps and Power Automate/Flow).

The expected functionality is shown within the following Microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/field-service/cfs-iot-central-alerts

Both the IOT Central application and Logic app are within the same resource group. Unsure if this is due to the resource locations differing?

[image: Cant see IOT central in application dropdown]

[image: IOT central application is in the same resource group]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your IoT Central application is using features that are in preview (ex. if you created your app using one of the solution templates from https://apps.azureiotcentral.com/build, or manually created a custom app based on the "Preview Application" template), which seems to be the case based on the URL of your app ("water-consumption-monitoring"), then you won't be able to use Power Automate / LogicApps connectors as they are not supported for now.

Comment: Thanks this worked. Had to choose legacy 2018 instead of a 'preview' application.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing and it took me a while to figure it out. I finally found it when I read [this piece of documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/iotcentral/#known-issues-and-limitations).

> Microsoft personal accounts (such as @hotmail.com, @live.com,
>   @outlook.com domains) are not supported to sign into the IoT Central
>   connector. You must use an Azure Active Directory (AD) work or school
>   account.

Now they mention hotmail and outlook etc. But this goes for any personal Microsoft account. Instead, I ended up making a new tenant in Azure that I now use for Central.